# How does the Chrome Setup.exe work under the hood on a Windows PC?

Tags: .net, deployment, google-chrome, setup-project, setup-deployment

Chrome has a very smooth installation process and I would like to imitate this setup behavior  in my own application.

How can I leverage this in .NET?  What are the limitations?

Is there any comparable Microsoft technology in the .NET Framework? (or comparable to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer is an open source project called [Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/), with a high-level overview [here](http://omaha.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/OmahaOverview.html).

Ultimately, Chrome installs to the current user's directory (i.e. C:\Users) on Windows Vista/7, so it can avoid the UAC prompt. I'm not sure if this is how Omaha works, or if that's just how Google decided to install Chrome.

Comment: Yup, thus bypassing UAC.  Invented specifically to stop viruses that worm their way into the machine through the browser from deploying themselves.  That's going to make a nice head-liner some day.